# mssql multiple queries insert queries and results

Tags: sql-server, insert

In php I'm executing multiple queries at once, the queries are wrote in one big variable.
These are insert queries and I have to retrieve each autoincrement "id" of the records created in the db. How to do it ?
The results set retrieved don't seems to keep each single result but just one.

Comment: Are you doing multiple insert in one qurey??

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are talking about an OUTPUT clause from the insert statement.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx

```
CREATE TABLE #t (id int identity (1, 1), f1 nvarchar(20 ) ) --the table that has the identities
CREATE TABLE #ids ( id int ) --the table to store the inserts into table #t

INSERT INTO #t ( f1 ) OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO #ids SELECT N'AAAA'
INSERT INTO #t ( f1 ) OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO #ids SELECT N'BBBB'
INSERT INTO #t ( f1 ) OUTPUT INSERTED.id INTO #ids SELECT N'CCCC'

SELECT * FROM #t

SELECT * FROM #ids
```

Another way is to use [`@@IDENTITY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933167%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) or [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) [SQL Authority link discussing/comparing them](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/03/25/sql-server-identity-vs-scope_identity-vs-ident_current-retrieve-last-inserted-identity-of-record/)

```
CREATE TABLE #t (id int identity (1, 1), f1 nvarchar(20 ) )
CREATE TABLE #ids ( id int )

INSERT INTO #t ( f1 ) SELECT N'AAAA'
INSERT INTO #ids SELECT @@IDENTITY --OR you can use SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO #t ( f1 ) SELECT N'BBBB'
INSERT INTO #ids SELECT @@IDENTITY --OR you can use SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

INSERT INTO #t ( f1 ) SELECT N'CCCC'
INSERT INTO #ids SELECT @@IDENTITY --OR you can use SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()

SELECT * FROM #t
SELECT * FROM #ids
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer and sorry for the absence,    
I mean if I use multiple insert queries in just one string variable like    `"INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...) VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);    INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...) VALUES (value4,value5,value6,...);    INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...) VALUES (value7,value8,value9,...);"`    how to retrieve each IDENTITY ?